# error when calling the metaclass bases function() argument 1 must be code not str

Tags: python, twilio, apache-nifi

I followed this to set up twilio: https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/send-sms-text-messages-python.html

The imports seem to be working when I run locally using python send_sms.py

Then, I use Apache Nifi ExecuteScript processor to execute the send_sms.py file and assume it should be same as if I am running the file locally.

It shows me the error:

> error when calling the metaclass bases function() argument 1 must be code not str

When I am trying to: `from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient`.

Twilio was installed at path /sendsms/lib/python2.7/site-packages, so I set the Module Directory to this path

Does anyone know what is wrong here? I am really stuck and please help.

Answer (score 3):

ExecuteScript uses Jython (not Python) to execute pure Python scripts, and as such any imported packages (and their dependencies) must be pure Python modules as well. I am guessing that TwilioRestClient (or its dependencies) include a non-pure Python module (compiled C, e.g.). For these cases, Jython (and thus ExecuteScript) will not work.

An alternative is to use the ExecuteStreamCommand processor, with which you can shell out to your Python interpreter (and script).